# How do I find out how my .NET Core app is configured to run on an Ubuntu VM with NGINX?

Tags: server, nginx

I'm working with a .NET Core app running as a systemd-based service, on an Azure-hosted VM that's running NGINX. (The VM is commissioned as a development environment). I've set up an A-record using Azure DNS, to point to the server IP. When I enter the specified hostname (`myapplication.mycompany.com`) in the browser, I see the NGINX welcome page:

[image]

When I enter a URL that I expect to return the application version number, I see a 404:

`myapplication.mycompany.com/version.txt`

When I run `systemctl status myservicename`, I see that the .NET Core service is started, and that the main service is running as follows:

```
   CGroup: /system.slice/myservicename.service
           └─...PID... /usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/myservicename/myservice.dll
```

When I then look in `/var/aspnetcore/myservicename/wwwroot`, I see the file `version.txt`

`curl -v localhost:5000` returns a `302 found`, stating `Server: Kestrel`, so I *believe* that Kestrel is serving the service on port 5000

When I look at the NGINX config on the *production* VM (which is a very similar image, running a comparable instance of the .NET Core service), I don't see anything that looks like it's doing any special hookup to Kestrel. I look at the NGINX config by using:

`cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

`cat /etc/nginx/conf.d`

(these files look identical to the ones on the development VM)

Where should I be looking, to determine what the configuration is for routing requests to the .NET Core app? And is there anything obvious that may be causing the 404 when I request `...hostname.../version.txt`?

**UPDATE**

I found out that `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` on the NGINX web server has some of the main settings. So I added a setting for the server name that matches my hostname.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapplication.mycompany.com;
```

When I vist `myapplication.mycompany.com/version.txt` I still get the `404`:

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there are 2 config files that determine the availability of a website:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

They both need similar routing configured, to determine the websites that are available and enabled on the NGINX server:

Both of the config files set the port (80) that NGINX uses for listening to requests, and set the server_name, which links the Azure DNS hostname to the NGINX web server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapplication.mycompany.com;
```

The config also determines how requests are reverse proxied (esentially ‘forwarded’) onto Kestrel, where requests are then handled by the app via the .NET Core MVC routing

```
location / {
    ... cacheing stuff

proxy_pass <http://localhost:5000;>
```